# How to access variable outside class in my example?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

```
class testing():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def house(self):
        d = self.a+self.b+self.c
        print d

module="hello"
p = testing(1, 2, 3)
p.house()
```

How do I access `module` variable from within my `testing` class?  I know I could just add it as a parameter to the class constructor by doing:

```
p=testing(1,2,3,module)
```

But I don't want to do that unless I have to.  What other ways can I access `module` variable from inside the `testing` class?

Comment: If the variable is defined above the class, you can just reference it the same way you would reference it anywhere else. However, **THIS IS A TERRIBLE IDEA**. Just pass it to the constructor.

Comment: Almost ... so long as the variable is defined before the reference (instantiation), the reference will succeed.  But I agree that this looks like a baaaaaad idea in the first place.

Comment: Actually, you can even define it after instantiation... as long as you don't call the method that references it until it's defined.

Answer (score 8):

You simply reference it; you don't need any special global permission to access it.  This isn't the best way, but since you haven't described your application and modularity requirements, about all we can do right now is to solve your immediate problem.

By the way, your a, b, c references are incorrect.  See below.

```
class testing():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.greeting = module

    def house(self):
        d = self.a + self.b + self.c
        print d
        print self.greeting

module="hello"
p = testing(1, 2, 3)
p.house()
```

Output:

```
6
hello
```

Comment: Note that if you put `greeting = module` at class level instead of inside the init method, this will fail with a NameError.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `globals()`. But I'm not sure if this is good idea at all.

```
class testing():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def house(self):
        print(globals()['module'])
        d = self.a + self.b + self.c
        print(d)


module = 'here'
t = testing(1, 2, 3)
t.house()
```

Output:

```
# here
# 6
```

Comment: `print module` has the same effect; a free variable in a method is looked up in the global scope.

Comment: OK, I see. But using globals is more explicit. Anyway, this is not clear way of doing things and I do not see any advantages over parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand the question, it already works since the global variable "module" is defined before you instantiated the class.

```
class testing():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def house(self):
        d = self.a+self.b+self.c
        print module
        print d

module="hello"
p = testing(1, 2, 3)
p.house()
```

outputs:

hello

6